# saving authentication data on the LocalStorage react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, axios

I am developing an application in Reactjs and using axios to work with the requests and I need to keep the user data saved in the localStorage, however this is missing something in my code, as it is undefined in the value where it was to be the data that I need.

File SingUp

```
class SignIn extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: "" };
    }

    handleSignIn = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        if (!email || !password) {
        this.setState({ error: "Preencha e-mail e senha para continuar!" });
        } else {
            try {            
                const response = await api.post("login", querystring.stringify({ email, password }));            
                login(response.data.token);
                console.log('ttttt', login(response.data.token));            
                this.props.history.push("/menu");
            } catch (err) {
                this.setState({
                error:
                    "Houve um problema com o login, verifique suas credenciais. T.T"
                });
            }
        }        
    };

***********************

    <form onSubmit={this.handleSignIn}>
    {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="E-mail"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                className='form-control'
            />
            <br />
            <label>Senha:</label>
            <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                className='form-control'
            />
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-md-4'>                            
                <button type="submit" >Log In</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 

***********************
```

API file

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getToken } from "./auth.js";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://localhost/aplicacao",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});

api.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    const token = getToken();
    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
});

export default api;
```

Auth File

```
export const TOKEN_KEY = localStorage;
export const isAuthenticated = () => localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY) !== null;
export const getToken = () => localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
export const login = token => {
    localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
};
export const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
};
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "teste1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "jest ./test"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/enzyme.setup.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-check-auth": "^0.2.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure that token is a string. Localstorage can only handle strings

Comment: Likely `response.data.token` is `undefined`. You should check the network tab of your developer tools to verify the response you're getting includes a `token` field in the response body. It would also be helpful if you'd paste a sample response into your question.

Comment: @JemiSalo

I do not know if I'm doing it correctly, but when I check it, this is what appears.


I put developer tools images in the topic

Comment: Hello @HelderGrunewald as Deckerz pointed out, localStorage can only handle strings in your DevTools output I can see a JSON and no `token` if you want to save the whole JSON you must first use `JSON.stringify(response)` and then `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))` to be able to use the JSON values. Hope this helps, cheers, sigfried.

Answer (score 1):

If the token is to be delivered to the client as a cookie, it should be found under the `set-cookie` header of an HTTP response. You can access it as `response.headers['set-cookie']` in axios. Some further parsing may be required as the header is in the syntax `key=value`. In your case it may look like `token=1234567890abcdef`.

Note that the sample response you provided does not seem to include this header. You will first need to get a response that does.

The rest seems to be working despite a dubious bug. In your Auth file the first line

```
export const TOKEN_KEY = localStorage;
```

you likely meant to be more like

```
export const TOKEN_KEY = 'some-string';
```

.

You're using the `localStorage` object as a key, which makes no sense, but javascript's type coercion stringified it into `'[object Storage]'`.

The key-value pair `'[object Storage]'` and `undefined` in your localStorage show that the token is saved correctly. The header `Authorization: Bearer undefined` shows that the token is correctly included in your requests, too. The token just happens to be `undefined`.

Comment: thanks @Jemi Salo, i changed the first line of file Auth, and I tried put the JSON.stringify(response) and JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')) as sigfried said, but I did not succeed. I talked with my manager about backend, he said the token in backend it is a cookie.

Comment: If the token is sent to the frontend as a cookie, it should appear under the `set-cookie` header of the response. The sample response you've shown has no `set-cookie` header, though. You should be able to see the token in your browser developer tools (`Storage -> Cookies` in Firefox) after it is set. Verify that you've received the cookie. I will update my answer to reflect this new information.